# Target one element element with same class

Tags: javascript

I have something like this. I want to be able to target one element from multiple elements with same class.

Can someone please help me.

```
<div data-id = '1' class = "anchor anchor1">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="label">
            Button 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-id = '2' class = "anchor anchor2">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="label">
            Button 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-id = '3' class = "anchor anchor3">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="label">
            Button 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(".anchor .label").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        var anchorId = $(this).parent().parent().data('id');
        //Do stuff 
        console.log(anchorId);
    });
});
```

Comment: what element you want to find?

Comment: Sorry was not very clear... so when I hover on Button 2 for example, I want to add class "active" to element anchor2.

Comment: Your code is working - the console.log shows the ID of the element being hovered over. What do you want it to do, that it's NOT doing now?

Comment: And by "element anchor2" you mean the div with the class of anchor2?

Comment: Yes thats right mrrrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answers in the comments, you can do this to add the class of "active" to the parent div with the anchor class, when a div with a label class is hovered over:

```
$(".label").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        //let anchorId = $(this).parent().parent().data('id');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

In answer to OP's question of how to remove the "active" class from the other anchor-classed divs, add this just before or after the line  `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');`:

```
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Warning: This entire answer is predicated on the HTML structure staying the same -- that is, the individual anchor/label elements will continue to be structured like this:

```
<div class="anchor">
    <div>
        <div class="label">
            Button
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this DOM structure ever changes so that the anchor divs are not the parent().parent() of the label divs (ex., if you got rid of the div between them), you would need to update the code, or you would need to approach it differently to not depend on DOM structure.

Comment: O so easy! what if I want to remove "active" from its siblings, and have it only on the hover element?

Comment: You can use .siblings and .removeClass() for that. I'll edit my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the target element an ID like this.

```
<html>
<style>
.box{
  /* stuff to apply to all of them*/
}
#target{
 /* stuff that applies to just the target */
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" id="target"></div>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mrrrow, this one works

```
$(".label").each(function() {
   $(this).hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   });
});
```